# App.config does not work?

Tags: c#

i have my App.Config Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

 <connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.dataConnection"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=address;
              Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and when i want to use following code to get connection string , "Error 1 'Weather.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'dataConnection' and no extension method 'dataConnection' accepting a first argument of type 'Weather.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) " error rises ,

```
string connectionString = 
   global::MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.dataConnection;
```

Comment: no i did not place theme

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve a connection string from the config file you could use the [ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx)  property:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.dataConnection"]
    .ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the error message has this namespace:

```
"Weather.Properties.Settings"
```

While you are referencing

```
"MyProject.Properties.Settings"
```

Check that your namespaces are the same.

Comment: i solved it , i rebuild the project and clicked Setting Tab In Properties Section Of Project , Thanks All of you